# FCM push notification closes automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've set up an FCM notification for my angular web app which will be triggered from the backend at certain time periods.

After triggering the notification, it will stay open for several seconds before closing itself automatically.

Is there a way to set the notification to remain open until I click on it or close it?

:: EDIT::

As requested, here is the simplified code from my script. I'm not too sure if there is a setting to let the notification remain open until action is taken on it.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {  
    console.log('Push message received', event);
    console.log('Started', self);

    event.waitUntil(registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
        .then(function(subscription){
            fetch("MY_ENDPOINT").then(function(response) {
                response.json().then(function(data){
                  var title = "Random Title";
                  self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
                    body: "body",
                    icon: "icon",  
                    tag: "tag"
                  });
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.error("Unable to retrieve data", err);
                var title = "Something went wrong!";
                return self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
                    body: "body",  
                    icon: "icon",  
                    tag: "tag"
                });  
            })
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Hello @czosel , I've added my code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep a notification open, you'll have to send a data only message and show your own notification and then you can use the web API's `requireInteraction` parameter to keep the notification visible.

**Note:** the notification only goes away after a certain period on desktop browsers, this doesn't occur on Android.

The code would look like this:

```js
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png',
    requireInteraction: true
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});
```

To learn more about the [requireInteraction parameter, I've put some notes here](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/chapter-05/03-notification-behaviour/#requires-interaction)

Comment: Hi @Gaunt Face, I've tested it out and it works! Appreciate your help!